# Change color combined with timeout

Tags: colors, timeout, intervals

I have a timeout interval and want to change the color of hop1 und hop2 each interval. The color change at 1000ms, 900ms, 800ms and so on. Why does my code doesn't work?

```
                var interval = 1000;
                var change   = 1;

                function callback() {

                   interval -= 100; 

                              if (change = 1)
                   {
                     mainContent1 = document.getElementById("hop1");
                     mainContent1.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFF99";
                     mainContent2 = document.getElementById("hop2");
                     mainContent2.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
                     change += 1;
                   }

                   else if (change = 2)
                   {
                     mainContent2 = document.getElementById("hop2");
                     mainContent2.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFF99";
                     mainContent1 = document.getElementById("hop1");
                     mainContent1.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
                     change = 1;

                   }
                    setTimeout( callback, interval, change);
                 }

            setTimeout( callback, interval, change);
```

Comment: Use `==` instead of  just `=` in the `if` clauses! A single `=` will do an assignment and not a comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code to this and make sure you stop calling the setTimeout after you get to the intended interval:

```
            var interval = 1000;
            var change   = 1;

            function callback() {

               interval -= 100; 

                          if (change == 1)
               {
                 mainContent1 = document.getElementById("hop1");
                 mainContent1.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFF99";
                 mainContent2 = document.getElementById("hop2");
                 mainContent2.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
                 change += 1;
               }

               else if (change == 2)
               {
                 mainContent2 = document.getElementById("hop2");
                 mainContent2.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFF99";
                 mainContent1 = document.getElementById("hop1");
                 mainContent1.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
                 change = 1;

               }
                setTimeout( callback, interval);
             }

        setTimeout( callback, interval);
```